# In app purchase loads empty list from the store

Tags: objective-c

Its usually working, but now i have an app at the store **already**, and i have added to it an in-app purchase item on iTunes-connect-and now i want to check it on xcode before launch.

When the callback function load the list, i can see its empty, and i cant understand why?

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"Loaded list of products...%@",response.products);  // its nil array  !
    _productsRequest = nil;

    NSArray * skProducts = response.products;
    for (SKProduct * skProduct in skProducts)
    {
        NSLog(@"Found product: %@ %@ %0.2f",
              skProduct.productIdentifier,
              skProduct.localizedTitle,
              skProduct.price.floatValue);
    }
```

What could it be ?
I have set 2 items already to that app,but he cant see them ..

Comment: Do you log in with a test user Apple ID?  Note: You need to logout from Settings > iTunes & App Store, then run the app and login with the test user Apple ID + password.

Comment: yes i know, i do log like that. thanks a lot but its probably something else .